# How to map an array of object

Tags: reactjs

I have an object like this:

```
const arr = {
  "items": [{
    "id": "61f5530ffa13c013c514cc5f",
    "name": "Classic",
    "slug": "classics",
    "unit": "1 each",
    "stock": 200,
    "price": 500,
    "quantity": 3,
    "itemTotal": 1500
  }],
  "isEmpty": false,
  "totalItems": 3,
  "totalUniqueItems": 1,
  "total": 1500,
  "meta": null
};
```

How can I map the above to an h1 element?

I tried this, I know it's wrong

```
  const myarr = arr.map((item) => {
     return <h1 key={item.id}>{item.name}</h1>
 });
```

Comment: Map it to _what_ `h1` element? What are you expecting to render? It seems like the only problem is you're trying to `.map` across an _object_, not the array that's one of its values.

Comment: What is your expected Output because First key value pair is Array

Comment: Yes, your array isn't an array. You probably want to map `arr.items`. Might be good to not name an object `arr` in the first place. Give it a descriptive name.

Answer (score 1):

Your `arr`  is object and `arr.Items` is array. so you can iterate as

```
const myarr = arr.items.map((item) => {
 return <h1 key={item.id}>{item.name}</h1>});
```